# Bootstrap 4: what is the best way to swap one icon with another inside of a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to swap `fa fa-plus` for `fa fa-minus` when using collapse, without every icon toggling at the same time while using a foreach loop.

here's a demo of my code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container h-100">

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>
</div><!--container-->
```

https://codepen.io/benwhittaker25/pen/rNVWyby

What is the best way to achieve this in bootstrap 4.4?

Comment: What have you tried already? where's the loop? I can't imagine why you tagged this for PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [events Bootstrap triggers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) when clicking on the button:

```js
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  // Find the corresponding button
  var $btn = $('[data-toggle="collapse"][href="#' + this.id + '"]');
  // Find the corresponding row
  var $row = $btn.closest('.row');
  
  // Toggle classes
  $btn.toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
  $row.toggleClass('rounded rounded-top');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container h-100">

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>
</div><!--container-->
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks for the help

Comment: what if i wanted to change `rounded` to `rounded-top` in the row div? i've tried adding `id="collapse"` to the row but i don't really understand `this.id` so this toggles all of my rows

`$('[id="collapse"]').toggleClass('rounded rounded-top');`

Comment: @Benwhittaker25 `this`, here, is the `collapse` element on which the event is happening. That being said, once you have a reference to the button (using the previous version of my answer), you can get the corresponding row using jQuery's [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. I updated my answer to do that

Comment: JavaScript seems to be a much more difficult language to learn compared to what I’m used to (html,css,php), maybe it’s because  the syntax is so different. FYI there’s a typo in your new code, rounted-top should be rounded-top. Thanks for the help, it’s very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The elegant way would be to do the jquery way shown by blex. But you can also bind a click function as well like below the javascript way:

```js
function toggleClass(item){
 if(item.classList.contains('fa-plus')){
   item.classList.remove('fa-plus');
   item.classList.add('fa-minus');
 }else{
  item.classList.remove('fa-minus');
   item.classList.add('fa-plus');
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container h-100">
<div class="container h-100">

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1" onClick="toggleClass(this)"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 1</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2" onClick="toggleClass(this)"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 2</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>

 <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">demo 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 ">
   <a class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3" onClick="toggleClass(this)"></a>
  </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
  <div class="row no-gutters border-0 rounded align-items-center mt-3" >
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">demo 3</div>
  </div><!--collapse-->
 </div>
</div><!--container-->
```

Comment: I can understand how to code this way much easier than the jquery way, because I only understand basic JavaScript. Thanks for the insight